# Возможна ли замена переменных средствами PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

Есть файл, назовем его params.ini, имеющий следущее содержание:

```
{param: variable1} = sample1
{param: variable2} = sample2
{param: variable3} = sample3
```

Есть каталог Test, с вложенными каталогами и файлами.
Задача, скриптом PowerShell получить значения переменных из файла params.ini и заменить их во всех найденных файлах всех каталогов в папке Test по маске, предположим во всех файлах *.sql,*.json,*conf.
Помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

```
$vars = @{}

([regex]"\{param:\s*([\w\d]+)\}\s*=\s*([\w\d]+)").Matches((Get-Content C:\tmp\param.ini -Raw)) | % {
    $vars.Add($_.Groups[1].Value, $_.Groups[2].Value)
}

Foreach ($file in (Get-ChildItem c:\tmp\002\* -Recurse -include ('*.sql', '*.json', '*.conf'))){
    $vars.Keys | ForEach-Object {
        (Get-Content $file.FullName) -replace $_, $vars[$_] | Set-Content $file.FullName
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо!
На выходе получаю в файле:
asdfasdfasfd
{param: sample1}
dfasdfasdfs {param: sample2} asdfasfdasf
Test asdfasdfasdf {param: sample3}!!!sadfasfdasf
Что-то делаю не так?

Comment: Возможно я неверно понял постановку задачи.

Скрипт считывает из ini в хеш пары ключей variable1 = sample1 Пробегаюсь рекурсивно по всем файлам в каталоге удовлетворяющим фильтру, ищет в фалах строки "variable1", "variable2", "variable3" и меняет их на "sample1", "sample2", "sample3" соответственно.